# iphone how to capture simple login/logout event from web to native

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am developing iPhone application which loads login page of my website. I am able to load my login page using phonegap/childbrowser. I am newbie to JS, Phonegap.

How do my native/phonegap application should handle logout and login event has performed on the webpage? Please guide me how to know user has logged out.

Also is it possible to add support for Push Notification in phonegap/childbrowser application ? How?

So far have seen facebook login-logout questions around but hard to understand and couldnt simulate similar approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your whole app run using the childbrowser? If so why not just have the login log out as piece of your app?

Also if you have to use the childbrowser best bet is to set up a locationchange event and if the location equals a login success page then append some arguments and store those using localstorage.

example -

```
client_browser.onLocationChange = function(loc){
  locationchange(loc);
};

function locationchange(loc){
  if(loc.indexOf("http://www.example.com/success?login=true&user=foo") > -1){
    var user = loc.match(/user=(.*)$/)[1]; // grab user info
    localStorage.setItem('login','true'); // set login as true
    localStorage.setItem('user',user); // set username
  }
}
```

that will save to your app locally that the user is logged in and their username, which you can use later if you need to use the childbrowser by passing that in the url you open and on the server side you'll have to look for those arguments.

to log out just open the childbrowser and send a logout argument
www.example.com/logout?user=foo

and in your localStorage 
localStorage.setItem('login','false');

Honestly this is kind of a vague question, it would really help to understand why you're wanting to do this in the childBrowser vs your app...

Comment: Thanks Drew,Yes,my app uses childbrowser. what i want to do is quite similar to any web based email website like gmail. For example, my first page in childbrowser is my client's login page say www.example.com/login. Should i keep copy of login page into my xcode workspace? Also after successful login as u mentioned some URL like www.example.com/home will be loaded at that time i can save information. Now such page contains logout link or button, How can i capture its click event in childbrowser? Please guide me as i have very little knowledge of web development, i am objective-c guy.

Comment: I would suggest using ajax for what you're trying to do... jQuery ajax works great - and you can do everything you're wanting in app. You cannot get callbacks from the childBrowser so doing everything in app is the best solution. You can create callbacks from your ajax and pass all the data you want around...

Comment: i've no idea of jQuery and ajax, can u provide me sample/tutorial? You are saying that i should build iphone-phonegap application without using childbrowser plugin? If yes how should I load first/login page? Thanks for valuable guidence